# Looping Core Data Objects outside a Table/ Collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I want to loop through the objects in CoreData without using a tableView or CollectionView... But using a ViewController

I tried something like:

```
for var i = 0; i < numberOfExerciseItems; i++ {          
  let exerciseItemsfromDay = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(i) as! ExerciseItemModel
}
```

This obviously doesn't work since it is not of `NSIndexPath` type as you'd get in a table or CollectionView. Are there ways to do this outside a Table / Collection View? Thanks for the ideas in advance.

**Edit**
From this answer, I'd want to access an entity from an item in the items array in the loop :

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ExerciseItemModel")
let items = (try? context.executeFetchRequest(request)) as? [ExerciseItemModel] ?? []

In this loop 
items.forEach {
    print(items) //Displays all the objects in the console. 
    print(items[1].attribute //Throws the error Value of type'AnyObject' has no member 'attribute' and I cannot access an attribute from the items array . Not sure why!

}
```

**Edit** My ExerciseModel Class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

    @objc(ExerciseItemModel)
    class ExerciseItemModel: NSManagedObject {

    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

    }

    extension ExerciseItemModel {

        @NSManaged var exerciseType: String?
        @NSManaged var exerciseName: String?
        @NSManaged var durationOrSets: String?
        @NSManaged var distanceOrReps: String?
        @NSManaged var weight: String?
        @NSManaged var backgroundImage: NSData?
        @NSManaged var dayID: String?
        @NSManaged var date: NSDate?

    }
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use a fetched results controller? Just execute an ordinary fetch request and loop through the returned array.

Comment: @MartinR I want to compare them to a value and filter certain objects. If you don't mind would you post some example code of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ExerciseItemModel")
let items = (try? context.executeFetchRequest(request)) as? [ExerciseItemModel] ?? []

items.forEach {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

A small example. Not exactly an answer so I'll delete it when a proper answer has been posted. This example will not show you any error messages if there are any, just keep that in mind.

Edit:

You're using `forEach()` incorrectly:

```
items.forEach {
    print($0)             // Print's the object in items  
    print($0.attribute)   // Should print the attribute
}

print(items[0].attribute) // Probably same error, but it should be used outside the loop
```

Comment: Cool. Hopefully I will figure out the right answer and post it back up. Thanks. ;)

Comment: Now that I think about it, it actually does answer your question ;)

Comment: It certainly does. ;) . Thanks

Comment: One last Question. I am trying to figure out how to access one of the attributes. A print(items) line in the for loop prints all the items in the console but if I try items[0].attribute to access one of the attributes, I get the error:  Value of type'AnyObject' has no member 'attribute', which is rather strange.

Comment: Can you show me your code so I can help you easier :). You can edit your question or open a new question if it's a whole new problem :)

Comment: Can you show me the code for class `ExerciseItemModel`? The objects in `Items` should be instances of `ExerciseItemModel` so you should be able to access it. I've updated the answer a bit but will need more info to help you. Also if you `option` / `alt` click `items`, what does it say?

Comment: I have added the class for the ExerciseItemModel. You should be able to see the attributes there. :)

Comment: I figure out the problem. I have declared an items variable i.e. var items = [ ] and had not made it of type ExerciseModel. Now it's working fine. Thanks again for your help @Eendje